# Why does https://api.atlassian.com/oauth/token/accessible-resources returns an empty list?

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api, confluence, confluence-rest-api

Call to this api - **https://auth.atlassian.com/oauth/token** with the body -

**`{ "client_id": "<client id>", "client_secret": "<client secret>", "grant_type": "client_credentials", "scope": "read:account read:me read:confluence-content.summary" }`**
gives **response **as -
**`{ "access_token": "<access token>", "expires_in": 3600, "token_type": "Bearer", "scope": "read:account read:confluence-space.summary manage:jira-data-provider read:me manage:jira-webhook read:confluence-groups manage:confluence-configuration report:personal-data read:confluence-content.all read:confluence-props read:jira-user read:confluence-content.permission write:jira-work manage:jira-configuration readonly:content.attachment:confluence manage:jira-project write:confluence-groups read:confluence-user read:confluence-content.summary search:confluence read:jira-work write:confluence-space write:confluence-content write:confluence-file write:confluence-props" }`**

On using the access token provided in the response of this api call, I call **https://api.atlassian.com/oauth/token/accessible-resources** , but it returns an empty list.